# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - Controls collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, textbox, webmatrix

I'm new to Asp.net and site building, but I started with Webmatrix Webpages and I'm actually progressing very much in my website.
But I'm now stuck in a piece of razor code. I get the error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
in line:
foreach(Control c1 in Page.Controls)

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("DOM Coins");
    var codigo_campo_ID_unico=0;
    var valor_BC=0;


    if(IsPost){

        foreach(Control c1 in Page.Controls){
            foreach(Control c in c1.Controls){
            if (c.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"){
                if (c.ID=="BC_8"){
                   if (c.ID.Substring(0,2)=="BC"){
                      codigo_campo_ID_unico=int.Parse(c.ID.Substring(3,c.ID.Length-3));
                      valor_BC=int.Parse(Request[c.ID]);


                       db.Execute("UPDATE Coleccao SET Quantidade_BC=@valor_BC WHERE Id=@codigo_campo_ID_unico");
                   }
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Teh reason I want to do this is because I'm creating textboxes dinamically, each one with a different ID, and I want to iterate through all of them and insert the data to the DB.

Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Dinis.

Comment: Post example how do you add controls to page?

Comment: Unfortunately Razor doesn't use Web Controls.  Controls as a concept are for WebForms and the `Page` object is only available on a WebForm.  It's giving you that error because you're trying to access the `Controls` property on the null `Page` object

Comment: It's something like this:  
    @foreach (row in db.Query("SELECT * FROM table1"){  
      <input type="TextBox" ID="@row.ID_unico">@row.BC</input>  
    }

Comment: ok, so is there any workaround for this, besides going to WebForm?

Comment: @D1N15 Yes, just build <input type="text" /> elements dynamically, rather than using a Server control.  It works just as well.

Comment: @Brian Mains That was just what I did. I didn't use server controls. But how iterate through these elements with razor?

Comment: @D1N15 OK, but above is a reference to a TextBox object, which doesn't exist in Razor.  You have to check the Request.Form collection to get the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the following creates a form with a variable number of text fields and reads their content storing it into a list.

```
@{
    var num = 3; // number of text fields to create
    List<string> nText = new List<string>();
    if (IsPost)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            var name = "txt" + i.ToString();
            nText.Add(Request.Form[name]);
        }
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            @for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                var name = "txt" + i.ToString();
                <p>@name
                <input type="text" name="@name" />
                </p>
            }
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

With small changes you could insert the text fields values into table records.

Comment: Thanks. I was not using the "name" in the input fields, so the request.form was not returning anything. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are using asp.net web pages, not MVC, correct?  You want to render out:

```
<input type="text" id="xxxx" />
```

as markup, not add elements directly.  Then, above this, check the response for the ID's entered by querying the form collection:

```
@{
   var ids = Request.Form.Keys.Where(i => i.StartsWith("BC"));
   //can process values here and store in dictionary, or process at render time
}

//Rerender textboxes - would have to base on ID's posted, or query again from DB
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I didn't explain it well.  I have a form with a submit button and a couple of dynamically created textboxes.  All I need is to insert/update the textboxes text in the database when the user presses the submit button.  For this I need to iterate through all of the textboxes in the page, whose quantity I don't know.

Comment: @D1N15 you can't iterate through the textboxes; there is no such thing as a textbox control in Razor.  What you do is iterate through the Form collection.  The form collection has the keys (the IDs of the textboxes) and use Request.Form.Get("") to get the values.  Razor is a completely different approach than web forms.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me how to do it? Because the line you mentioned the "where" method is not recognized, and I can't really understand how to achieve what I need, using this. Thanks